# Apk path not exported when building multiple flavors and deploying to Google Play from Fastlane

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, continuous-integration, android-productflavors, fastlane

I'm using Travis and Fastlane to build and publish my app to Google Play Store but when handling multiple flavors at the same time, Supply cannot find the APKs to upload them.

This is my fastfile:

```
fastlane_version "2.59.0"

default_platform :android

platform :android do

  before_all do
      gradle(task: "clean")
  end

  desc "Submit Whitelabels to Play Store"
  lane :whitelabels_playstore do
      gradle(
          task: 'releaseWhitelabel'
      )

    lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_ALL_APK_OUTPUT_PATHS].each do | apk |
        puts "Uploading APK to Play Store: " + apk
        begin
            supply(
                skip_upload_images: true,
                skip_upload_screenshots: true,
                validate_only: true,
                apk: apk
            )
        rescue => ex
            puts ex
        end
    end
  end
end
```

The task releaseWhitelabel code is:

```
def releaseTask = tasks.create(name: 'releaseWhitelabel') {
  group 'Whitelabel'
  description "Assembles and release all Whitelabels"
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {

    variant.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
      def flavorName = flavor.name.capitalize()
      def releaseFlavorTaskName = "releaseWhitelabel${flavorName}"
      def releaseFlavorTask

      flavorsMap.each { name, jsonItem ->
        if (flavorName.toUpperCase().startsWith(name.toUpperCase())) {

          releaseFlavorTask = tasks.create(name: releaseFlavorTaskName) {
            group 'Whitelabel'
            description "Assembles and release build for flavor $flavorName"
          }
          releaseFlavorTask.dependsOn variant.assemble
          releaseTask.dependsOn releaseFlavorTask
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The task works perfectly when running locally when I execute the lane, I get an error saying that `lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_ALL_APK_OUTPUT_PATHS]` cannot be nill.

When I run the following gradle config, I works properly but only one flavor can by published this way and my flavors are generated dynamically.

```
gradle(
    task: 'assemble',
    flavor: 'Dell',
    build_type: 'Release'
)
```

How can I have the `lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_ALL_APK_OUTPUT_PATHS]` updated properly with the path of each apk built?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I took was control all whitelabels using a JSON file and get data from there.

```
  lane :whitelabels_playstore do
    gradle(
        task: "whitelabelRelease"
    )

    begin
      # Retrieving Flavors from JSON file
      require "json"
      file = File.read "../buildsystem/whitelabels.json"
      data = JSON.parse(file)

      # Supply will deploy each flavor to Play Store
      data['list'].each do | whitelabel |

      begin
        supply(
            // application_id_suffix is provided by JSON file
            package_name: "my.app.package.#{whitelabel['application_id_suffix']}",
            skip_upload_images: true,
            skip_upload_screenshots: true,
            // flavor_nameis provided by JSON file
            apk: "app/build/outputs/apk/app-#{whitelabel['flavor_name']}-release.apk"
        )
        rescue => ex
          puts ex

          slack(
              message: "Error uploading => #{/([^\/]*)$/.match(apk)} #{get_version_name} - #{get_version_code}: #{ex}",
              slack_url: "SLACK_HOOK_URL",
              success: false,
              default_payloads: [:git_branch, :lane, :test_result]
          )
        end
      end

      rescue => ex
        puts ex
    end
  end
```